# Android app automatically navigating to different activity upon incoming push notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I built an android chat application with Firebase functions and firebase cloud messaging. But I realised soemthing pretty strange. Before the notification shows up, the app will navigate automatically to the main activity. What could be the problem? I simply have no idea as to why this happens. I guessed it was from my OnMessageReceived but I am not sure. I'll post it below so it'll be easier to trace the error.

**My OnMessageReceived**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("name"), (remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action")), remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        }


    }

    private void showNotification(String name, String click_action, String title) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (click_action) {
            case "Download":
                intent = new Intent(this, Download.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "Student_SystemsDevt":
                intent = new Intent(this, Student_SystemsDevt.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "Chats":
                intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            default:
                intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(name)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Below is the structure;

```
"data" : {

 "name" : "What's up", 
"title" : "Upward Studios", 
"click_action" : "chats"

 }
```

Comment: What [type of message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) are you sending?  Notification with data payload?

Comment: Yes please. It is a data payload notification

Comment: You state: "Before the notification shows up, the app will navigate automatically to the main activity."  Is this when the app is active or is the app in the background when the notification comes?.

Comment: When the app is active. As in, if it's still in activity stack. When it goes to the main activity, then it'll show the notification. What could be wrong?

Comment: It is a simple text message to another user. Before it pops up on the other side, that particular one will open the main activity. And then the notification pops up.

Comment: When you say structure, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The docs I linked in my comment explain how the Firebase SDK handles messages differently depending on if they contain only notification, only data payload, or both.  Please indicate what type of message you are sending: notification only, data only, or both.

Comment: The JSON structure of the message like: "{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}"

Comment: @BobSnyder The type of message is a data payload.

Comment: @Barns I have updated the question

Comment: @BobSnyder The docs are not easy to understand. Could you break it down for me?

Comment: You did not provide the complete message structure. A data messages have only custom key-value pairs. You are using "click_action" in your "data" payload. I am not certain, but this might be causing an issue.  Also note that the java `switch` is case sensitive when using a `String`... you have "chats" (lowercase) in the message and "Chats" (uppercase)  in the `switch` statement!

Comment: That's not the issue Barns. I fixed everything and still it's malfunctioning.

Comment: This question was [asked again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51228271/4815718) with added details and subsequently resolved.