# App malfunctioning when firebase notification pops up

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to devices when they receive messages from their friends. But if they are about to receive the pop up, the app automatically goes to the homepage before the message even shows. I just don't get it. The messages are both data and notification types. I just can't tell where the error is from. Please help. Below is my code.

JS code.

```
exports.sendNotification8 = functions.database.ref('/Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notifications_id}')
    .onWrite((change,context) =>{

    var user_id = context.params.user_id;
    console.log(user_id);

    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();

    var device_token = admin.database().ref('/Users/'+user_id+'/device_token').once('value');

    return device_token.then(result => {

    var token_id = result.val();

    console.log(token_id);

    var str = eventSnapshot.message;
    console.log(eventSnapshot.from);

    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: eventSnapshot.from,
            body: str,
            click_action: "Chats",

        } ,
        data: {
            from_user_id: eventSnapshot.from_user_id,
            name: eventSnapshot.from,
            user_id: user_id
        }
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

    });

    });
```

My onMessageReceived

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            String name = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
            String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");
            String texter_name = remoteMessage.getData().get("name");
            String user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("user_id");

            showNotification(from_user_id, texter_name, user_id, name, title, click_action);

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    }

    private void showNotification(String name, String title, String click_action, String from_user_id, String texter_name, String user_id) {

        String GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.dreamlazerstudios.gtuconline";

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_action);
        resultIntent.putExtra("from_user_id", from_user_id);
        resultIntent.putExtra("texter1", texter_name);
        resultIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);

        Intent intent;
        switch (click_action) {
            case "Download":
                intent = new Intent(this, Download.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "Download_Ent":
                intent = new Intent(this, DownloadEnt.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "InfoSys":
                intent = new Intent(this, MIS_Information.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "EntSystemsInfo":
                intent = new Intent(this, EntSystemsInfo.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "DatabaseInfo":
                intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseInfo.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "IntroToOil":
                intent = new Intent(this, DownloadIntro.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "IntroInfo":
                intent = new Intent(this, IntroToOilInfo.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "Student_SystemsDevt":
                intent = new Intent(this, student_mis.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            case "Chats":
                intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
            default:
                intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;
        }

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(name)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that when the message is received, the app's main activity opens without the user doing anything?

Comment: Yes please. What could be the problem

Comment: I can't understand how that could be happening with the code you have posted.  Are you sure this is the `onMessageReceived()` code that is executing? You're going to have to experiment to understand why this is happening.  As a first step, try commenting out the call to `showNotification(...)` to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Ok lemme do that.

Comment: I tried what you said Bob. This time the notification doesn't appear but it still goes to the main activity. What's wrong here?

Comment: Very strange.  Hard to debug on SO.  Maybe try a different device or emulator.

Comment: I tried different devices please. Even currently, I tried to update my profile picture on my account in the app. It did the same thing and took me to the mainpage

Comment: Just don't get it

Comment: When you say "mainpage", do you mean the main activity of your app or the phone's launcher screen?

Comment: My app's main page

Comment: The home screen

Comment: I've figured it out Bob. The malfunction erupted from the onstop and onstart methods not being called in the main activity. The authstatelistener had to be removed and added but I didn't notice